# NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate methods don't get called

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have this in my viewWillAppear method

```
[RPCoreData
 getFetchedControllerForCategoryDiscoverDelegate:self completion:^(NSFetchedResultsController *controller) {
     self.fetchedResultController = controller;
     self.fetchedResultController.delegate = self;
 }];
```

and this in my CoreData.m

```
+ (void)
getFetchedControllerForCategoryDiscoverDelegate:(id<NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate>)delegate
                                     completion:(void (^)(NSFetchedResultsController *controller))
                                                    completion {
    [MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {
      NSFetchedResultsController *controller = [ItemData MR_fetchAllGroupedBy:@"category.id"
                                                                withPredicate:nil
                                                                     sortedBy:@"category.id"
                                                                    ascending:NO
                                                                     delegate:delegate
                                                                    inContext:localContext];
      completion(controller);
    }];
}
```

Comment: What is "RPCoreData" class here? is this any 3rd party library for Coredata? if yes can you please share the link where can i get "RPCoreData" Library

Comment: Recently I've received a code which was developed in 2012 it has RPCoreData and RPCoreDataHelper class files related code, but missed those files in the xcode, and we tried to reach the person who developed it, but could not find him... it would be very helpful if you share the link or RPCoreData Files

Comment: RP was a core data helper method that was abbreviated from the project name. It would be no use to you as it contains project specific logic and wasn't meant to be reused outside of the project as well as containing confidential information to the project. It's just a coindence that we named it the same as the file you are looking for.

Comment: is that file developed for "Real Page" pvt ltd?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to wrap the creation of a `NSFetchedResultsController` around a `saveWithBlock:` from `MagicalRecord` since you are effectively only fetching objects, not changing them.

I do understand why you did it though (in order to get a local `NSManagedObjectContext`)

`MagicalRecord` has a convenience method that does not require you to pass a `NSManagedObjectContext`:

```
+ (NSFetchedResultsController *) MR_fetchAllGroupedBy:(NSString *)group withPredicate:(NSPredicate *)searchTerm sortedBy:(NSString *)sortTerm ascending:(BOOL)ascending;
```

This will use the context for the current thread you're in during execution, so if you're not doing anything too complex like switching between threads and managing different contexts, you should be fine with it.

This way your method should be able to return a `NSFetchedResultsController` right away, without using blocks.

Moreover, it seems like you are setting up the `delegate` twice, once inside the block and once when passed as a parameter to the `MR_fetchAllGroupedBy:..`

Finally, make sure your newly created `NSFetchedResultsController` is not `nil`, and implement one of `delegate` methods in the same class as your `viewWillAppear:`, then use breakpoints/logging to see if they are called:

```
- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    NSLog(@"objects: %@", controller.fetchedObjects);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the Following lines in ViewDidLoad

```
id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    self.managedObjectContext = [delegate managedObjectContext];
```